# Matrix multiplication - double array calculation in java

Tags: java, arrays, operators, double, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to do a matrix multiplication using double arrays for an assignment but the arrays' values can neither be added nor multiplied using operators such as + or *= . What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MatrixMultiplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Initializing all required arrays
        double[][] matrix1 = new double[][] { { 3.0, 2.0, 1.0 },
                { 1.0, 0.0, 2.0 } };
        double[][] matrix2 = new double[][] { { 1.0, 2.0 },
                { 0.0, 1.0 },
                { 4.0, 0.0 }};

        double[][] intermediate = new double[][] { { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 },
                { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 },
                {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}};
        double[][] result = new double[][] { { 0.0, 0.0 },
                { 0.0, 0.0 }};

        //check arrays' lengths and heights
        if ( matrix1.length == matrix2[0].length) {

            //multiply first line and first column
            for (int i = 0; i == matrix1.length; i++) {
                intermediate[i] = matrix1[i] * matrix2[0][i];
                result[0] += intermediate[i];
            }

            //multiply first line and second column
            for (int i = 0; i == matrix1.length; i++) {
                intermediate[i] = matrix1[i] * matrix2[1][i];
                result[1] += intermediate[i];
            }

            //multiply second line and first column
            for (int i = 0; i == matrix1.length; i++) {
                intermediate[i] = matrix1[i][1] * matrix2[0][i];
                result[0][1] += intermediate[i];
            }

            //multiply second line and second column
            for (int i = 0; i == matrix1.length; i++) {
                intermediate[i] = matrix1[i][1] * matrix2[1][i];
                result[1][1] += intermediate[i];
            }

            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result).replace("], ", "]\n"));

    } else {

        System.out.println("Matrices can not be multiplied"); }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit please? Is it an error or a wrong answer?

Comment: `matrix1[i]` is an array and you can't multiply an array with a scalar. You can only multiply scalars.

Comment: You need nested for loops to iterate over the whole 2 dimensional array and multiply the double values and not arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
   //multiply first line and first column
    for (int i = 0; i == matrix1.length; i++) {
        intermediate[i] = matrix1[i] * matrix2[0][i];
        result[0] += intermediate[i];
    }
```

you need to specify a method to do array multiplication. you can't multiply a column of an array with a scalar directly. You can mimic multiplication by hand (multiply each element and add them, then put it in the correct index).

Comment: I didn't know that! Thank you very much for troubleshooting my code.